# How to pass variable to docker-compose and dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Im using docker-compose:

```
version: "3"

services:
   app:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

And dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk

WORKDIR /app

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# copy and build everything else
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "out/testapp.dll"]
```

And my question is, how can I pass param to docker-compose and dockerfile using docker-compose up command?

***Solution:***

I use this code "variable=value docker-compose up" to send a variable to docker-compose adding this code in the docker-compose file

```
  environment:
        - variable=${variable}
```

And use the entrypoint in this format in Dockerfile:

```
ENTRYPOINT dotnet "testapp.dll" "$variable"
```

Comment: What "param" do you want to pass? Could you provide an example of such a param in your question? Maybe you'd mean [build args](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#set-build-time-variables---build-arg) or [environment variables](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/)?

Comment: @norbjd I need to use a command (per default Im using docker-compose up) to up the container, and my code receive this param (string) to start. And this param I need to pass to the code by docker-compose > Dockerfile.

Comment: Is this param used in the `ENTRYPOINT` directive of your `Dockerfile` (like `out/testapp.dll`), or in a `RUN` command?

Comment: @norbjd Seem he wanna pass `ENV` variable

Comment: @norbjd exatcly! I need to use in entrypoint...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to use [environment variables](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/). Declare an environment variable (`DLL` here for example), like this :

```
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      - DLL=out/testapp.dll
```

And then, use it in your `Dockerfile` as an environment variable (last line) :

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk

WORKDIR /app

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# copy and build everything else
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

ENTRYPOINT dotnet "$DLL"
```